# Debugger Console : strange messages

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

When I'm showing a graphe (that is made on javascript) trough a UIWebView, there are a lot of error messages in the Debugger Console. This is always the same message :

```
<Error>: CGContextSetLineDash: invalid dash array: at least one element must be non-zero.
```

How can I fix it???

PS: I don't draw any graph, it's a javascript graph that's showed trough the browser (UIWebView)

Thanks to help me, that error is killing me :-)

Comment: Hi clement. i have same problem. did u find any fix for this???? can u plz help me with this

Comment: I wonder if it’s the web console’s output. Can you check Safari desktop to see if the web console outputs the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your graph is amCharts, they already know about it and will [probably] fix it. Here is a link to where they discuss this issue and it might answer your question at some point.
http://www.amcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=9650

Comment: You're right ! It causes no problem but it's annoying when you try to debg with all those messages :-)